# Not getting homepage in response from Requests.post, redirecting to login

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to authenticate to a webapp using the python requests library, when I attempt to do so as shown below, the response only contains the body of login.php when it should be redirecting me to index.php. The status code is 200 but it doesn't appear to be authenticating and posting the data correctly.

```
payload = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'}
url = 'http://localhost/login.php'
response = post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: From Python side this looks ok, maybe there is error on PHP side. Have you tried to log on PHP side to see what is happening?

Comment: Did completely depends on what your server-side PHP expects. Did you compare your python HTTP trace to a in-browser (working) HTTP trace ?